# Reading data from Arduino (Pyqt5)

Tags: python, arduino, pyqt5, sensors, com-port

I have problems with reading data from Arduino.
I created an app with PyQt5 and tried to read data from Arduino, which was connected to an optical sensor to detect things.
My script shows for me only amounts of registered objects but doesn't sum them.
With the function `onRead` I read the line and tried to accumulate all detected objects, but I received only objects which was registered on time not total.

In the end I want to build an app which will show online register of objects

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort, QSerialPortInfo
from PyQt5.QtCore import QIODevice


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
ui = uic.loadUi('design.ui')
ui.setWindowTitle('SerialGUI')


serial = QSerialPort()
serial.setBaudRate(9600)
portList = []
ports = QSerialPortInfo().availablePorts()
for port in ports:
    portList.append(port.portName())
ui.comL.addItems(portList)


def onRead():
    tot = 0
    rx = serial.readLine()
    rxs = str(rx, 'utf-8').strip()
    i = int(rxs)
    
    tot = tot + i
    print(tot) 

def onOpen():
    serial.setPortName(ui.comL.currentText())
    serial.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)

def onClose():
    serial.close()

ui.runB.clicked.connect(onOpen)
serial.readyRead.connect(onRead)
ui.stopB.clicked.connect(onClose)


ui.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: your `tot` variable is local to the `onRead` function. You need to make it a global variable.